# Tag for items not burnable in lava (like netherite)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

Nice and simple.

What is the tag for items to be not burnable in lava, like netherite ingots? Or how would I make other items like obsidian not burn?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, there's no tag for that, it's just how Netherite items work.

This was posted on [Minecraft suggestions](https://www.reddit.com/r/minecraftsuggestions/comments/f1i2ck/add_an_nbt_tag_for_whether_an_item_is_flammable/):

> Add an NBT tag for whether an item is flammable or not